# CakePHP: HTTP Header is being interpreted as part of my static content (JS, CSS)

Tags: apache, cakephp, squid

I'm encountering a strange error in my web app running CakePHP 2.6:

Random static content files are taking forever to load, and when they do take forever to load, they don't work properly. These files are living where I generally assumed they were supposed to: `/app/webroot/css` and `app/webroot/js`.

In this screenshot, a JS file takes 10 seconds:
[image: Static content takes forever to load.]

When the static content is JavaScript, it triggers a syntax error:
[image: Syntax Error]

Previewing the response, we see that the HTTP header is being interpreted *as part of the script*. The JS engine sees the header and throws a syntax error.
[image]

This also happens randomly when it's a different HTTP code, like 304 Not Modified:
[image]

An example of the response when it *doesn't* take forever to load:

[image]

And an example of the header when it doesn't take forever to load:
[image]

Could there be something I've got misconfigured in my Cake app? The fact that this is happening seemingly randomly is really driving me nuts.

Comment: Requests for "real", existing files in the `webroot` folder normally never hit PHP at all, such requests are being exluded via `mod_rewrite` and handled directly by Apache. I'd start searching the problem at the Squid side of the story.

Comment: Not particularly helpful but I've seen these symptoms before. Check the actual headers (or simply the whole response as received) - what are the "valid" headers that are received for one of these borked requests? Are they the headers from a previous request?

Comment: A [related question with similar symptoms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31967457/761202).

Comment: Interesting. My issue is intermittent... still trying to track this down. Will update when I encounter it again.