# Getting invalid status line 10380HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: php, android, http, cakephp, android-volley

It's driving me crazy. I created an Android App that does REST requests to an Apache Server running CakePHP 2.X.

- In Android side: the request are make using Volley from Google it's HEAD version.
- In Server side: It's a Apache 2, PHP 5.4, CakePHP 2.x and SSL.

Whatever request method GET or POST, with the same URL or same parameters when POST, sometimes the response is fine others time I get `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 10380HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

When the error happen, the only thing i noticed is the number before changes.

```
10380HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

.

Any idea?
Thanks

I could sniff the request/response and could confirm it's a server side issue.

[image: stack trace]

[image]

Comment: Looks like garbage from the preceding HTTP response. Maybe somebody tries transfer-encoding: chunked and doesn't get it right?

Comment: I think so.. but it'd be always a number, may be a size/length information?

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt anyone will be able to answer your question - the best you can do is try to determine where `10380` comes from, or what it means. Borked chunked encoding indeed sounds like a viable cause [here's another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754298/cakephp-http-header-is-being-interpreted-as-part-of-my-static-content-js-css).

Comment: I see, i have the application server installed in two different servers staging and production, in both happen the issue. So I guess the error is in client side. I tried get the error doing requests with cmd line cURL and JMeter, the responses were fine. Do you know another tool that I can use to test my servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With information from [@Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) and [@AD7six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761202/ad7six)

Apparently it's common error when using keep-alive and the second,third,etc response was messing up.

So following the information i got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time), the problem looks like solved (I'll keep testing it).